# Finding: $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \bigg(\frac{1-\sqrt[5]{(1+x)^3}}{x}+(1+3\sin(x))^{\frac{2}{\sin(x)}}\bigg)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, limits

I'm quite confused by this example of finding the limit$$\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\sqrt[5]{(1+x)^3}}{x}+(1+3\sin(x))^{\frac{2}{\sin(x)}}$$

I know that if the limit goes to 0, I need to multiply by the conjugate.

I know to do it in term of $x^{1/2}$, but how I do it in this case?

Comment: The limit is not $0$.

Comment: This should be a side limit because the exponent is not defined for small negative x

Answer (score 1):

What is the derivative of $g:x\mapsto (1+x)^{3/5}$ at $x=0$?  We have,

$$ \lim_{x\to0} \frac{1-(1+x)^{3/5}}{x}= \lim_{x\to0} \frac{(1+x)^{3/5}-1}{x-0}=-g'(0)= -\frac35$$
on the other hand, since $t=\sin x\to 0$ as $x\to 0$   we have,
 $$\lim_{x\to0}(1+3\sin(x))^{\frac{2}{\sin(x)}} =\lim_{t\to0} (1+3t)^{\frac{2}{t}} =\exp\left(6\frac{\ln(1+3t)}{3t}\right)=e^6$$

Comment: Typo : you should have $e^6$ instead of $6$. Also instead of $\sim$ better to use the substitution $t=\sin x$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh thanks

Comment: Thanks, Guy I understand your answer perfectly clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the factorization $$(x-1)(x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1)=x^5-1.$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

The first term being $$A=\frac{1-(1+x)^{3/5}}{x}$$ use the binomial theorem $$(1+x)^a=1+a x+\frac{a(a-1)}2 x^2+\cdots$$